# PDF problems with Evince on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, evince

One of my collegues is trying to print a PDF that our designer has sent him, created using Adobe InDesign CS4 (6.0.4).

When he opens it up using Evince (version 2.28 on Ubuntu 9.10 thin client) it displays exactly how we expect it to, however when he prints it's not rendering correctly, for example:

1. Missing one logo, the other dozen display perfectly
2. Missing a white box with 30% opacity (without this the blue text sits on a light blue background)
3. The dotted border of a box is screwed up (missing dots in the corners, but fine on the straights)
4. Finally the font quality is slightly poorer than a print out we've done on a working machine.

I have tried it on my Ubuntu dev box (Evince version 2.22 on Ubuntu 8.04 server) and it displays and prints perfectly.

Can anyone offer an explanation as to why this might be happening, I find it hard to understand how an older version of Evince is displaying it better than a newer version.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Just for anyone surfing in, it's likely yo be a CUPS problem on our server, cheers ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we upgraded the cups server and the printing problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say it, but I have had several problems with Linux PDF readers. If I'm struggling, I just report a bug and install the Adobe reader.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, we had discussed but never actually implemented Adobe Reader into our thin client images, I'll have a play and see what I can find, I'll return later.

Comment: Ok so I've installed Adobe Reader, on my machine (the dev rig, the one that works) but it's displaying the colours a lot brighter than they should be, it still prints fine though???

Comment: Scratch that, they are appearing darker... giving them a more vivid appearance.